# generating spectrogram form wav file nodejs and save it

Tags: javascript, node.js, fft, spectrogram

i'm new in the world of javascript and i wanted to recreate a project of mine (written in python) with javascript.

so i want to write a script with nodejs that reads a wav file and generate from it a spectrogram.

I used `node-wav` , `canvas` and `audio-context` trying to recreate the method applied in this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spectrogram)

I'm working with local files from my laptop and with javascript client side. I want to do everything locally. This is my code :

```
const canvas = createCanvas(480, 240)
const spectro = spectrogram(canvas, false)
    const spectrogramsGenerator = async () => {
        // wavfiles return a list of wav files (it works)
        const files = await wavFiles()
        for (file in files) {
            const buffer = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file/' + files[file])
            spectro.connectSource(buffer, audioContext)
            spectro.start()   
        }        
    }
```

with that code snippet i get the following error :

```
   /path/to/workspace/node_modules/spectrogram/spectrogram.js:34
        window.onresize = function() {
        ^

    ReferenceError: window is not defined
        at new Spectrogram (/path/to/workspace/spectrogram/spectrogram.js:34:5)
        at Spectrogram (/path/to/workspace/node_modules/spectrogram/spectrogram.js:16:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/workspace/spectrogram.js:13:17)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
        at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
```

if this the wrong way doing it (i think it is) .. what packages should i use to achieve my goal or how should i approach this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `window` not being defined would imply that this is not running in the browser the way you expect it. Could you try following the example given in the spectrogram.js repo here https://github.com/miguelmota/spectrogram and see if you get a similar error?

Comment: That's the thing. I need to generate the spectrogram without going through running the script on the browser. The script is going to be deployed later on as a firebase function and use it's ouput (spectrogram.jpg) to do further work. Is there a way doing that without using a canvas ? Or my approach is totally false?

Comment: spectrogram.js depends on having a browser, since it uses `window` and other variables like that in the source code. If you must use it, you can spin up a headless browser (there are npm packages for, say, chromium headless), render the spectrogram, then do something with that. I have seen this done before, but since it requires a lot of overhead, I would suggest trying something else first. You just need a way to do the conversion with JS, so you can read the github source code and find what you need (it's not that large of a codebase).

Comment: i ended up using puppeteer since google started supporting headless browser last year for app engine and firebase functions, here's the [news  link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-headless-chrome-support-in-cloud-functions-and-app-engine) from google. Thanks for the tip :D